# Getting "null" while converting from ArrayList to JSonArray

Tags: android, arrays, json

I am wondering how it is possible that converting my ArrayList to JSonArray I do get a lost of date.
The array is perfectly filled, that's how the logcat shows:

```
ArrayList: [{sp_pod=0, et=Mike}, {sp_pod=1, et=Charlie}, {sp_pod=2, et=Paul}]
JSONArray of ArrayList: [{"sp_pod":0,"et":null},{"sp_pod":1,"et":null},{"sp_pod":2,"et":null}]
```

And this is the code:

```
Log.e( TAG , "ArrayList: " + listArray );
Log.e( TAG , "JSONArray of ArrayList: " + new JSONArray( listArray ) );
```

Any clue, please?

PS: I would like to avoid using GSon since I don't need advanced JSon management, only sending and getting json from a server

**EDIT**

I've tried to change the "logic" of construction of the ArrayList, but it is like JSONArray doesn't accept strings!

Comment: its working. see  ArrayList: [{et=Mike, sp_pod=0}, {et=Charlie, sp_pod=1}, {et=Paul, sp_pod=2}]
JSONArray of ArrayList: [{"et":"Mike","sp_pod":0},{"et":"Charlie","sp_pod":1},{"et":"Paul","sp_pod":2}]

Comment: How is that possible?? Could it be the emulator?

Comment: No....On device

Comment: What type of objects do you have in the `ArrayList`? I see that the `et` field is never written.